# OnItemClickListener for horizontal gridview

Tags: android, listview, android-gridview, horizontal-scrolling, onitemclicklistener

I have designed a view in android which has listview with custom adapter. Now every row item of this listview has horizontal gridview with custom adapter.
My problem is, when I am clicking on any particular item in the horizontal scroll view, I get the position of that item by using

```
gridview.onItemClickListener
```

But once I scroll my gridview horizontally, then even if I am clicking on its item my code doesnt goes inside the onclicklistener.
I am not getting whats the issue is. Is my gridview loosing the item focus , once I am scrolling it?

following is my listview adapter :

```
    /**
     * Array adapter for main vendor listview
     */
    private class VendorMainListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

        ArrayList<String> VendorNameArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

        private Activity activity;
        public VendorMainListAdapter(Activity a, int resource, ArrayList<String> VendorNameArrayList) {
            super(a, resource, VendorNameArrayList);

            activity = a;
            this.VendorNameArrayList = VendorNameArrayList;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            final View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_vendor_list_item, parent, false);

            final TextView tvVendorName=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tvVendorNames);
            final GridView gvCakeList=(GridView) row.findViewById(R.id.gvCakeList);
            tvVendorName.setText(VendorNameArrayList.get(position));

             int size=CakeNameArrayList.size();
            // Calculated single Item Layout Width for each grid element ....
            int width = 150 ;

            DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
            HomeScreen.this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
            float density = dm.density;

            int totalWidth = (int) (width * size * density);
            singleItemWidth = (int) (width * density);

            int height= 100;
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    totalWidth, singleItemWidth);

            gvCakeList.setLayoutParams(params);
            gvCakeList.setColumnWidth(singleItemWidth);

            gvCakeList.setStretchMode(GridView.STRETCH_COLUMN_WIDTH);
            gvCakeList.setNumColumns(size);

            gvCakeList.setHorizontalSpacing(10);

//Here I have set the adapter for the gridview 

            gvCakeList.setAdapter(new CakeListGridViewAdapter(HomeScreen.this,CakeIdArrayList,CakeNameArrayList,
                    CakePriceArrayList,CakePicArrayList));
            gvCakeList.setSelection(mSelected);

//this is the onitemclicklistener for this gridview

            gvCakeList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    Log.e("item clicked ", String.valueOf(i));
                }
            });

            row.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.e("oops","you clicked parent");
                }
            });
            return row;

        }

    }
```